why std::move(std::vector<int>) does not move
I'm really confused cause of C++ having so many "unspecified states". In the code below, I'm trying to move std::vector to a set(&&) function, but the output seems like it's not moved.
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void set(std::vector<int>& V )
{
    std::cout<<"lvalue "<<V.size()<<std::endl;
}

void set(std::vector<int>&& V )
{
    std::cout<<"rvalue,size:"<<V.size()<<"-->";
    
    for(int i : V)
        std::cout<<" "<<i;

    std::cout<<"\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> V = {1,2,3,4,5};
    set(std::move(V));
    set(std::move(V));
}

OutPut:
rvalue,size:5--> 1 2 3 4 5
rvalue,size:5--> 1 2 3 4 5

First call of set(std::move(V)) should have emptied the original V, at least it should have moved elements if not size.
Help me understand why elements are preserved in the original V.

should have emptied the original V -- Your assumption is wrong.

std::move by itself doesn't do anything. It's just a cast to an rvalue reference. You have to then pass it to something that treats an rvalue reference in such a way that something happens with it, like a std::vector constructor. Just binding the reference and calling .size() and iterating over it won't do those things.

std::move doesn't move, it just tells the compiler that you want to move something. In your code then only thing it does is make the second version of set be called. It's then up to your code (in the second version of set) to actually do the moving.

Your usage of std::move(V) is equivalent to static_cast<std::vector<int>&&>(V). Why would a static_cast modify the object passed to it?

Think about is this way, there is only one vector in your code V, everything else is a reference to that vector. So if std::move(V) by itself was going to move the vector elements, where would it move them to?

The std::move is only called that because Howard Hinnant's original proposal for std::permission_granted_to_suck_out_the_innards_leaving_behind_a_dessicated_husk_of_an_object_only_suitable_for_destruction_or_reassignment was considered — by some — to be too verbose.  Upshot is, std::move allows the item to be moved from, but does not do any moving in-and-of itself.

Dupe addresses a completely different question. There must be a dupe for this question because it's a common enough misunderstanding.

I've added a somewhat better dupe. It addresses this question but also a whole lot more.

@john Tip: You don't have to reopen and then close the question just to change the duplicate targets. There's a small edit button in the upper right of the close banner, which you can use to edit the duplicate targets (and also add additional targets if appropriate).

@john Regarding the dupe target, the logic of "It addresses this question but also a whole lot more" isn't appropriate for a target. A specific question shouldn't be closed with a target that's much broader, even if a target doesn't exist that answers the specific question. In this case, I feel the original target was answering exactly the OP's question (as is the additional specific dupe target which another user added to the list).

In your second set function, if you change the parameter from std::vector<int>&& V to std::vector<int> V then you will get the output you originally expected. https://godbolt.org/z/eaPTenMq4 This is tricky and subtle to me, too, but I think the explanation is that if set's parameter is an r-value reference, a new vector isn't created, so vector's move constructor isn't called. Instead set simply refers to the original vector.  But if set's parameter is a value param, then a new vector is created via vector's move ctor, and it's the move constructor that empties out the original V.
